# Angular Drop Down, Select by Index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am retrieving an unordered list and binding to a drop down here, but on instantiation I want to be able to select the 0th item in the drop down. `ng-init="selectedTreatment=treatments[0]"` doesn't work, as the list is reordered in the view.

```
<select ng-model="selectedTreatment" 
        ng-options="option.TreatmentName for option in (treatments | orderBy : 'TreatmentName')">
</select>
```

Is there an Angular way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution was to order the data in the controller, the same way as it is ordered in the view. Then in the controller I injected the `$filter` into the controller and did:

```
$scope.selectedTreatment = $filter('orderBy')($scope.treatments, 'TreatmentName')[0];
```

This allowed me to utilise the orderBy filter in the controller. This fixed my problem, but seems like it doesn't offer full SOC. A way to do this neatly in the view doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

In tour controller set the select ng-model

```
$scope.selectedTreatment = treatments[0].TreatmentName
```

Comment: Since the data is re-ordered using the `orderBy` filter on the view. The 0th item in the data isn't the 0th item in the drop down. So this doesn't work.